# Почему в результате работы программы добавляется None

Tags: python-3.x

```
def max(x, y):
    if len(x)>len(y):
        print ('Меньше второе')
    else:
        print ('Меньше первое')

x = str(input('Введите первое слово: '))
y = str(input('Введите второе слово: '))

print(max(x, y))
```

Результат получаю верный, но к нему дополнительно добавляется `None`. Почему?

P.S. Только начал учиться не ругайте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну потому что вы ничего не возвращаете из функции `max`, соответственно в строке

```
print(max(x, y))
```

и возникает `None`.

P.S. имя функции `max` это **ОЧЕНЬ ПЛОХО**, так как в питоне уже есть built-in функция с таким именем.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что Вы выводите результат, возвращаемый функцией `max`. А если функция явно ничего не возвращает, то её возвращаемому значению неявно приписывается `None`. В зависимости от того, что Вам нужно, код можно переписать в двух вариантах.

Первый вариант:

```
def max(x, y):
    if len(x) > len(y):
        print('Меньше второе')
    else:
        print('Меньше первое')


x = str(input('Введите первое слово: '))
y = str(input('Введите второе слово: '))

max(x, y)
```

Второй вариант:

```
def max(x, y):
    if len(x) > len(y):
        return 'Меньше второе'
    else:
        return'Меньше первое'

x = str(input('Введите первое слово: '))
y = str(input('Введите второе слово: '))

print(max(x, y))
```

---

Кстати, вашу функцию `max` можно записать короче:

```
def max(x, y):
    return 'Меньше второе' if len(x) > len(y) else 'Меньше первое'
```

Answer (score 0):

Все из-за `print`. Ему нечего возвращать вот и `None`.
`return` исправил ситуацию.

Comment: Нечего возвращать не `print`, а `max`.

Comment: Ответ неверный.